Double derivative representation in terms of $\theta$?
Ok, this is a thought I had, as we all know that we can write $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$ as $\tan(\theta)$ because it's just the slope of the tangent line. Thought I could get the double derivative in terms of $\theta$ as well, so I took the equation $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx = \tan(\theta)$ and differentiated both sides with respect to $x$, so I got $\mathrm d^2y/\mathrm dx^2 = [\sec(\theta)]^2\mathrm d\theta/\mathrm dx$. For $\mathrm d\theta/\mathrm dx$, I referred to the original equation $\tan\theta = \mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$; this implies that $θ = \arctan(\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx)$. Subbing this in at $\mathrm d\theta$, I get this:
$$
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\tan\theta
\\
\\\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\sec^2\theta \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dx}
\\
\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)
\\
\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\sec^2\theta \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dx}
\\
\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\sec^2\theta~ \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2}~\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}
\\
1=1
$$
The problem is that through the chain rule, there is a $\mathrm d^2y/\mathrm dx^2$ at the end of the last equation, and since $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$ is $\tan\theta$ subbing, that cancels everything out and gives $1=1$. I want to know if I am wrong or if I am abusing the differentials as fractions too much. Also, please tell me if there is a better way of approaching the problem of double derivative in terms of $\theta$.

We can express the double/second derivative $\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}$ in terms of intrinsic properties/quantities, such as the tangential angle $\theta$ and the curvature $\kappa$.
The first derivative $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\tan\theta$ involves only $\theta$ (tangential angle), whereas the double derivative involves an extra intrinsic quantity, like curvature $\kappa$.
Second/double derivative:
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\tan\theta)=\sec^2\theta\cdot\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dx}\implies\color{red}{\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{1}{\sec^2\theta}\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}}\tag{1}$$
Arc length:
$$\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dx}=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2}=\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}=\sec\theta\tag{2}$$
We have curvature:
$$\large\kappa=\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm ds}=\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm ds}=\frac{1}{\sec^2\theta}\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}\frac{1}{\sec\theta}\implies\color{red}{\boxed{\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\kappa\sec^3\theta}}$$
which shows that the double/second derivative corresponds to the curvature or concavity of the graph.

Exactly what I wanted, thank you sir!

@cdkw2 You're most welcome!

I have a query, doesnt the formula for the curvature also has the double derivative at the numerator? Does it not cancel it out again?

Yes! $\kappa=\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}$. Substitute $y'=\tan\theta$. You'll directly get that. I have used the formula (definition) of the curvature to derive that. It is the rate of change of the tangential angle ($\theta$) with respect to the distance ($s$) measured along the curve. The reciprocal of the curvature is called the radius of curvature. $\rho=\frac{1}{\kappa}=\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm d\theta}$. You can not expect the second-order derivative to be expressible in terms of only $\theta$ as it describes the curvature.

Hmmmm ok thank seems fine. I got a answer!

@cdkw2 That's why whenever you try to eliminate $\kappa$ and keep only $\theta$, you will get $1=1$ (no useful result). Also, note that if $x$ and $y$ have metre units, then $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$ will be dimensionless (as $\tan\theta$). But $\mathrm d^2y/\mathrm dx^2$ has the inverse of metre, so it can't be expressed in terms of only $\theta$.
